# Python Variable memory size

Tags: python, mongodb, memory, pymongo

I am trying to save timeseries data into MongoDB using pymongo. However the average object size is 14 bytes, while I need to store it in 4 bytes.

The issue is Python pre-allocates variables to 24 bytes (or based on the variable size, larger) , and after conversion in pymongo is a bloated collection.

For example :

```
x=1
sys.getsizeof(x)
```

24 Bytes

```
x=1000**1000
sys.getsizeof(x)
```

1356 Bytes

*The above example is an illustration, I am using smaller sizes, typically 32 bit for voltages current etc*
How can I ensure 4 byte fit to python variables and a smaller mongoDB timeseries collection

Comment: I'm very curious to know how you're going to fit 1000**1000 in 4 bytes...

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, that was an illustration, I am using smaller sizes, typically 32 bit for voltages current etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime size of the Python object is mostly irrelevant here - specially for small integers - since what get stored is a bson representation of the object not - obviously - the Python object itself.

Comment: if we try out : an example which is about a days worth of data every second   for i in range (60*24):     collection.insert({str(i+1):list(np.random.randint(200,250,60))})     I get an average object size of 560 bytes for each document < 60 values> I was expecting 60X4 240 bytes

Comment: Once again:  the size an object takes in _MongoDB_ storage 1/ is not the size of the Python object at runtime and  2/ is up to _MongoDB_, not Python.